# What does visitChildren() in antlr4 actually does ? (Java)

Tags: java, antlr4

What does `visitChildren()` in antlr4 (for Java) actually does ? It's the default function for everything in the base visitor and it seems to do a lot that I don't know. For example, what does it do with these parser rules?

1)

```
a: b | c | d;
```

2. 

```
e: F g H;
```

3. 

```
i: j k l+;
```

4. 

```
m: N O P?;
```

And do you have other examples to show what it does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visitChildren` iterates over all child nodes of a given node and triggeres the `accept` method for each of them. Look in your generated parser to see what the `accept` method does. Normally it calls the visit function of the next child in the chain or simply visits over its own children by calling again `visitChildren` (which has basically the same effect, just in a more general way). See the class `AbstractParseTreeVisitor` for the default implementation of `visitChildren` and other methods you can override to customize the visitor behavior.